# Visibility of class definition

Tags: python, django

This may be a simple Python question, however after searching for "imported name not defined" and similar criteria, I did not find an answer to this.

I have a models.py, as prescribed by django, with class definitions for all models.

I then have a loadtestdata.py which is simply a programmatic way to populate the database with some initial entries.

Within loadtestdata.py, I import all the models using "from myproject.models import *".

This seems to work as 'global code' within loadtestdata.py is able to see all the class names imported from models.py. It can populate the database just fine.

However *if I define a function* inside loadtestdata.py, suddenly that function is unable to see any of the imported class names.

For example, this function would not see ImportedModelName:

```
def AddSomeEntries(list1):
  for value in list1:
    new_model = ImportedModelName()
    # set some stuff on the model
    new_model.save()

AddSomeEntries([1,2,3,4,5])
```

However, I could write this and it sees ImportedModelName just fine

```
new_model = ImportedModelName()
# set some stuff on the model
new_model.save()
```

Why does the former example not see the imported class, but the latter example can?

EDIT:

I cut down the loadtestdata.py to its bare minimum and this is it

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.filter(email='someemail@here.com').delete()
User.objects.create_superuser('someuser', 'someuser@here.com', 'somepassword')

from django.db import models
from myproject.models import *

from datetime import datetime

def AddTestModel(list_data):
    for entry in list_data:
        test_model = TestModel()
        test_model.name = entry
        test_model.save()

AddTestModel([1,2,3])
```

In this file it fails because NameError: name 'TestModel' is not defined.

However if I replace the function AddTestModel with this:

```
for entry in [1,2,3]:
     test_model = TestModel()
     test_model.name = entry
     test_model.save()
```

It works just fine. Note: the above, aside from changing the database login particulars, is now *exactly* what is in my loadtestdata.py.

The models.py begins with this (it has many other model definitions which I can't strip out because django will complain, but they are all simple definitions which certainly cannot clash with a 'TestModel' name):

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please show a full version of the file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, the complete entry for loadtestdata.py is now added. Even the class name 'TestModel' is what I am using :)

Comment: I'll just add one other thing - obviously the loadtestdata.py needs to be run from 'within the context of django' so it can actually create the database entries. It is executed via: python manage.py shell < loadtestdata.py

Comment: This kind of problem is often due to a circular import. If you have any import loops, try to restructure your program to remove them. In the meantime, please post the complete stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In working through explaining this post, I had a random idea which (after some google searching) resulted in this:

When I execute the script I am doing so with this:

```
python manage.py shell < loadtestdata.py
```

I don't know how that is functionally different to this:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> exec(open('loadtestdata.py').read())
```

But the latter works (being that functions I define in loadtestdata.py are able to see the imported class names) whereas the former produces the 'name is not defined' error.